# What does this Regex mean?

Tags: php, regex

Can someone tell me what it's trying to match exactly?

```
$exp = '/[\s]+col[\s]*=[\s]*"([^"]*)"/si';
```

Comment: It can be compressed down to `/\scol\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"/i`

Comment: It means someone doesn’t understand regular expressions very well.

Comment: For those on windows platforms, the application "RegexBuddy" is pretty useful for understanding and constructing patterns.

Comment: @Scuzzy: I'm sure it runs on Wine too. But anyway, there are many for-free alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write regular expressions with comments, if you add the `/x` modifier. so here is a lengthy and documented version (always advisable for complex ones):

```
$exp = '/
          [\s]+     # one or more spaces
          col       #       col
          [\s]*     # zero or more spaces
          =         #        =
          [\s]*     # spaces
          "         #        "
          ([^"]*)   # anything but " and zero or more of it
          "         #        " 
    /six';
```

Also you sometimes see `[^<">]` in place of `[^"]` to make such regexps more resilient against malformed html.

Comment: Cute, the regex modifiers spell `six`.

Comment: Nice multi line syntax... although sometimes you'll find <> in an attribute and most browsers accommodate it.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be matching  `col="some value"`, while being very forgiving of whitespace around the equals sign, being case insensitive, and regardless of whether the value is empty or not.

On a side note, it's curious what the `s` modifier is doing there since there are no `.` metacharacters.

Comment: @Abdullah Jibaly: Yeah, probably just being a very forgiving regex.

Comment: @Abdullah So that it matches ` COL="<value>"` as well

Comment: Or possibly because HTML is case-insensitive.

Comment: @mario: That's what I thought. Which element has a `col` attribute? I know textarea has `cols` (plural)...

Answer (score 1):

I think others have already gave a good answer. As an aside, if this is not something for
parsing markup, then you could boost functionality on the string side with something like
this:

`\s+ col \s* = \s* "( (?: \\. | [^\\"]+ )* )"`

Perl'ish would be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex = qr/

    \s+ col \s* = \s* "( (?: \\. | [^\\"]+ )* )"

/sx;

my $string = q(
 col  =  " this'' is \" a test\s,
           of the emergency broadcast system,
           alright .\". cool."
);

if ( $string =~ /$regex/ )
{
     print "Passed  val =\n $1\n";

}
__END__

Passed  val =
  this'' is \" a test\s,
           of the emergency broadcast system,
           alright .\". cool.
```